# make a procedure in vb6 to clear textbox in current form

Tags: vb6

~
i need to make a procedure so that i wont be typing a code over and over again

i'm trying it in a textbox for now but it still wont work
condition:
clear the textbox in current form when the procedure is called

---

*case1

module:

```
sub cleartext
text1.text=""
end sub
```

form1:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
cleartext
End Sub
```

error - object required

---

*case2

module:

```
sub cleartext
form1.text1.text=""
end sub
```

form1:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
cleartext
End Sub
```

no error.. but i need to use it in every form

edit:

Module:

```
Public Sub ClearText(tb As TextBox)
tb.Text = ""
End Sub
```

form1:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
Call ClearText(Text1)
End Sub
```

it only worked if i have 1 textbox

it doesnt work on the 2nd textbox

Comment: It doesn't work on the 2nd textbox because you have to call `ClearText` for each textbox you want to clear (with the name of the textbox as the parameter).

Comment: Edited my answer with an option to loop through all the controls on the form, calling ClearText for the text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

module:

```
Public Sub ClearText(tb as TextBox)
   tb.text=""
End Sub
```

form1:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
   Call ClearText(text1) ' assuming text1 is your form's textbox name
End Sub
```

---

For a form with more than one textbox control you can loop:

```
   Private Sub Command1_Click()
    For Each cControl In Me.Controls
       If (TypeOf cControl Is TextBox) Then
          Call ClearText(cControl)
       End If
    Next
   End Sub
```

Comment: The type declaration for your ClearText procedure should be *somectrl* As *TextBox*

Comment: @TristanBailey: Thanks. Was writing VB6 but thinking in C#.

Comment: i tried the suggestion. please check my editted post~